# spring sts 3.7.2 how to block networking access

Tags: eclipse, spring

i am working in company as a java programmer and our stations are not open to internet (security reason ...)
i installed spring sts 3.7.2 in my station (instead eclipe luna).
the big problem is that "Spring sts" some time try to get out to internet like:
**!message connection to http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/doc/update.xml failed on connection reset.** (from the eclipse log file under .metadata)

for me it is happen when i try to open project (right click on the project)
my station is freezing for about 15 minutes.
in eclipse log file under.metadata library  i can see the internet access( as i wrote before)  and i do not know how to block it for ever for any reason.

in window->preference->automatic update i click off the **automatic update** option and in **available software** sites i click off the abillity to maybe get update from those sites.
window->preference->dashboard i clean the url there
but nothing help . it is still trying to get out to internet.
any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

> change the hosts file like
>
> 127.0.0.1    dist.springsource.com
>
> `instead`
>
> 127.0.0.1    localhost

hosts file path (c:\windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)

Still required internal solution from  `ECLIPSE SPRING STS`

Answer (score 0):

It's a different eclipse version
But,
Thank You. I'm working (2 steps works)

1_ Eclipse Tool Preferences Auto Update Item **Uncheck**

2_ **Add url** to Windows OS "hosts" file

- After starting Eclipse, right-clicking on the project no reponse issue is gone

  ▷ check your ".log" file

  ▷▷ file location : {workspace} ▷ .meatdata ▷ .log (**find out not Working URL**)
- Eclipse : Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) (korea e-gov Envrionment)
- {Eclipse}-{Menu} -> Windows ▶ Preferences ▶ Install/Update

  ▷ Automatic Updates

  ▷▷ **(Uncheck)** Automatically find new updates and nofify me
- **"hosts" add url text**

  ▷127.0.0.1 dist.springsource.com

  ▷▷ file location : (normal) C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Answer (score -1):

We had a similar issue.  It seems silly, but we simply unplugged our network cable before opening STS. After it loaded, we would plug it back in.  We were, however, able to resolve our issue by preventing the dashboard from coming up in the preferences after it was up.

It sounds like your issue is a little different.  Did you go under the Startup and Shutdown options and disable the plugins from auto starting?

Comment: Thank you 

i disabled the plugins from auto starting (window->preferences->startup and Shutdown and from now it's work well without freezing.

now the message in the log file is:

!ENTRY org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.core 2 0 2015-12-08 15:51:37.267 
!MESSAGE Couldn't read sts properties from 'http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/discovery/sts.properties' **internal default values will be used**